# What is keyboard shortcut to delete items in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

What is keyboard shortcut to delete items in Sitecore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appearently (in its user manual), there isn't one.

But you can create your own shortcut keys according to this blog post: http://istern.dk/blog.aspx